# Need to embed a media player onto my blog

Tags: html, embed, media-player

Kinda feel silly even bugging you guys with this, but to say I'm a total noob would be a gigantic understatement. So let's just assume I know less than nothing and take it from there, okay?

I've got a blog that's in dire need of some tunage, so I reached out for help and somebody sent me this piece of code...

```
< audio controls autoplay >

< source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9n6SAXnQdg"/ >

< /audio >
```

I popped it into the script right between a `< /b:if >` under the body section and the start of `< div class='body-fauxcolumns' >` Hope that was o.k and I'm not starting off by putting it in the wrong place.

Anyway, so HTML knowing that I'm a total idiot with this stuff gives me a hint. It says:

> Error parsing XML, line 619, column 17: Attribute name "controls" associated with an element type "audio" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

Gee, thx, HTML. I'll look right into that.

So there I go, pop the ol' = right in between controls and autoplay so the line now looks like this...

I go right ahead and press the magic "Save Theme" button and what's next?

> Error parsing XML, line 619, column 17: Open quote is expected for attribute "controls" associated with an element type "audio"

So I go ahead and do `< audio "controls=autoplay >`
But of course this is wrong 'cos I didn't close the " and so what follows is...

> Error parsing XML, line 619, column 8: Element type "audio" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Of course `< audio "controls=autoplay" >` doesn't work, because that just gives me

> Error parsing XML, line 619, column 8: Element type "audio" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

And neither does `< audio "controls"=autoplay >` because that just gives me

> Error parsing XML, line 619, column 8: Element type "audio" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

So, I'm well aware that I have dived deeply into the abyss of ignorance and am probably putting my own stupidity on grand display, so I will end my misery here and just say, HELP! What started out as a simple copy and paste job has unravelled into a time stealing nightmare.

Comment: just a suggestion, i feel like i am reading an essay and it's not leading me to a question, it's probably simple like you've said. I think it's just a simple syntax error, if no one answers, i'll take a better look when i get home.

Comment: Well, I guess if I knew what the problem was I would have the luxury of being more specific, but I don't, so I can't. Here's the bottom line. I'm trying to embed a media player onto my Blogger site. Somebody gave me this code:

< audio controls autoplay >
< source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9n6SAXnQdg"/ >
< /audio >

When I add it I run into all kinds of errors. So, I guess the question really is whether the code is right? Can you verify it? I'm running HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Only need to add css for it that you can inspect. It will be reponsive automatically

```
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.